# Change background of entire table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to make the entire row of a table change colour (either the background colour or text colour) based on the value of the column labelled "Status". If the value in the "Status" column is "Expired" the background of the entire row should change.

(Edit: The data is going to be pulled dynamically from a database).

Any suggestions?

### HTML Code

```
<table>
    <th>Bonus Competitions</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Link</th>
    <th>Expires</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <tr>
        <td>Cash</td>
        <td>£500</td>
        <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
        <td>18-Feb-17</td>
        <td>Active</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sports Car</td>
        <td>£5000</td>
        <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
        <td>18-Jan-17</td>
        <td>Expired</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you render rows?

Comment: Show code that you are using to set it dynamically; jquery, or directly through php looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change how the table is rendered than I would just add the text as a class. This will be the best performance option and requires no JavaScript and the content will not flash.

```css
tr.Expired td {
  background-color: red;
}
tr.Active td {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Bonus Competitions</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>Expires</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="Active">
      <td>Cash</td>
      <td>£500</td>
      <td><a href="#">Link</a>
      </td>
      <td>18-Feb-17</td>
      <td>Active</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Expired">
      <td>Sports Car</td>
      <td>£5000</td>
      <td><a href="#">Link</a>
      </td>
      <td>18-Jan-17</td>
      <td>Expired</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or you will need to run JavaScript code that reads the cell value and adds the class.

```js
$("tr:has(td:last:contains('Expired'))").addClass("Expired");
```

```css
tr.Expired td {
   background-color: red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Bonus Competitions</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>Expires</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cash</td>
      <td>£500</td>
      <td><a href="#">Link</a>
      </td>
      <td>18-Feb-17</td>
      <td>Active</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sports Car</td>
      <td>£5000</td>
      <td><a href="#">Link</a>
      </td>
      <td>18-Jan-17</td>
      <td>Expired</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `th` should not be direct child of table

Comment: I know, maybe it make sense to fix it also. Otherwise many people might consider it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

try using CSS only adding a class to the tr.

```
tr.active > td {
  background-color: green;
}

tr.expired > td {
  background-color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jt717mL8/

Answer (score 1):

In your case the status column is the 5th. So you may do something like:

```js
$('table tr:gt(0)').each(function(idx, ele) {
  if ($(ele).find('td:eq(4)').text() == 'Expired') {
   $(ele).css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
    <th>Bonus Competitions</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Link</th>
    <th>Expires</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <tr>
        <td>Cash</td>
        <td>£500</td>
        <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
        <td>18-Feb-17</td>
        <td>Active</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sports Car</td>
        <td>£5000</td>
        <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
        <td>18-Jan-17</td>
        <td>Expired</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What will happen if we decide to change text of `Expired` to something else, or maybe add icon? Right, will need to change JS code too. What happens if we want to change color or background? Change JS again! So in 4 lines of code you hardcoded two problems. It makes it pretty bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can first get index of status `th` and then check each `td` with same index and check its text.

```js
var i = $('th:contains(Status)').index();
$('tr').each(function() {
  var td = $(this).find('td').eq(i);
  if (td.text() == 'Expired') td.css('background', 'red')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <th>Bonus Competitions</th>
  <th>Value</th>
  <th>Link</th>
  <th>Expires</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <tr>
    <td>Cash</td>
    <td>£500</td>
    <td><a href="#">Link</a>
    </td>
    <td>18-Feb-17</td>
    <td>Active</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sports Car</td>
    <td>£5000</td>
    <td><a href="#">Link</a>
    </td>
    <td>18-Jan-17</td>
    <td>Expired</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I left this comment on another answer (removed now) but yours has the same problems. "Concentrated low quality in 4 lines or code. Hardcoding "Expired" word in code, changing css styles directly.. And finally, such things this should be handled during table rendering."